# Create multiple dictionaries from 4 lists using regex

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have the following txt file:

```
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
```

I want to create a function that converts these to multiple dictionaries where each line is a dictionary :

`example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", "user_name":"feest6811", "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700", "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}`

I was able to do this so far, create 4 lists for all the items but I didn't know how to create multiple dics for each line:

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        host = (re.findall('(.*?)\-',logdata))
        username = re.findall('\-(.*?)\[',logdata)
        time = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', logdata)
        request = re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',logdata)
        #for line in range(len(logdata)):
            #dc = {'host':host[line], 'user_name':user_name[line], 'time':time[line], 'request':request[line]}
```

Comment: So do you want a list of dictionaries? What is the current error with your code that you commented out?

Comment: it says syntax error. No I want a dictionary for each line of the text file

Comment: Can you copy and paste the precise syntax error into the question?

Comment: Try to fit all parts into a single regex, the position of each group will make it impossible for false positives as when you are matching a tiny parts separately. Using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) can help you to see the matching groups against testing data.

Comment: sorry it says: "list index out of range"

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet will produce a list of dictionaries, one for each line in the log file.

```
import re


def parse_log(log_file):
    regex  = re.compile(r'^([0-9\.]+) - (.*) \[(.*)\] (".*")')
    
    def _extract_field(match_object, tag, index, result):
        if match_object[index]:
            result[tag] = match_object[index]

    result = []
    with open(log_file) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            match = re.search(regex, line)
            if match:
                fields = {}
                _extract_field(match, 'host'     , 1, fields)
                _extract_field(match, 'user_name', 2, fields)
                _extract_field(match, 'time'     , 3, fields)
                _extract_field(match, 'request'  , 4, fields)
            result.append(fields)

    return result


def main():
    result = parse_log('log.txt')

    for line in result:
        print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this course rightnow and the answer i got is

```
import re
def logs():
with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
    logdata = file.read()

# YOUR CODE HERE

pattern='''
(?P<host>[\w.]*)
(\ -\ )
(?P<user_name>([a-z\-]*[\d]*))
(\ \[)
(?P<time>\w.*?)
(\]\ \")
(?P<request>\w.*)
(\")
'''

lst=[]

for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
    lst.append(item.groupdict())
print(lst)
return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you will fix the regex issues you have - the code below will work for you

```
import re

result = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for logdata in lines:
      host = (re.findall('(.*?)\-',logdata))
      username = re.findall('\-(.*?)\[',logdata)
      _time = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', logdata)
      request = re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',logdata)
      result.append({'host':host,'user_name':username,'time':_time,
    'request':request})
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.split()` and `str.index()` could work as well, ignoring the need for regular expressions. As well, you can directly iterate over the file handler, which yields a single line one by one so you don't have to load the entire file into memory:

```
result = []

with open('logdata.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Isolate host and user_name, discarding the dash in between
        host, _, user_name, remaining = line.split(maxsplit=3)

        # Find the end of the datetime and isolate it
        end_bracket = remaining.index(']')
        time_ = remaining[1:end_bracket]

        # Slice out the time from the request and strip the ending newline
        request = remaining[end_bracket + 1:].strip()

        # Create the dictionary
        result.append({
            'host': host,
            'user_name': user_name,
            'time': time_,
            'request': request
        })

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below function returns a list of dictionaries with the desired keys/values matched from each line of `assets/logdata.txt` based on your original question.

It is worth noting that proper error handling should be implemented on top of this as there are clear edge cases that may cause unexpected stoppage of code execution.

Please note the change to your `host` pattern, this is important. The original pattern used in your example matches more than just the `host` section of each line, the addition of an anchor at the beginning of the pattern alongside `re.MULTILINE` halts the matching of false positives that would be matched from the remainder of each line as in your original example.

```py
import re
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    host = (re.findall('^(.*?)\-',logdata, re.MULTILINE))
    username = re.findall('\-(.*?)\[',logdata)
    time = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', logdata)
    request = re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',logdata)
    return [{ "host": host[i].strip(), "username": username[i], "time": time[i], "request": request[i] } for i,h in enumerate(host)]
```

The above is a simple/minimal solution based upon your original post. There are much cleaner and more efficient ways that one might tackle this problem, however I thought it pertinent to work from your existing code to give you an idea of how it may be corrected - rather than just providing you with a better optimised solution that may mean little to you comparatively.